# Problem with Docker WORKDIR. Error is occuring "Cannot find module" when I run the image

Tags: node.js, docker

I've written a docker file.

```
FROM node:14 AS development

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=development

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:14 AS production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=production

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/main"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

Docker compose file

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  bot_constructor:
    build:
      context: .
      target: prod
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - ${HTTP_PORT}:${HTTP_PORT}
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${PG_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PG_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${PG_DB_NAME}
    ports: 
      - ${PG_PORT}:${PG_PORT}
    volumes:
      - bot_constructor_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  bot_constructor_db:
```

**When I built it, the error had occurred:**

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/dist/main'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Comment: Can you add your `docker run` command or docker-compose file to your post, so we can see how you run it?

Comment: If you `docker run --rm your-image ls ./dist`, is `main.js` there as you expect?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

The error message you're encountering suggests that Node.js is unable to find the main file (/usr/src/app/dist/main) when trying to start the application. This typically happens when the file specified in the CMD directive of your Dockerfile is not present or not located at the expected path within the Docker container.

In your Dockerfile, you've specified CMD ["node", "dist/main"], indicating that the main file of your application is expected to be located at /usr/src/app/dist/main within the container. However, it seems like either the build process or the copying process might not have worked as expected, resulting in the absence of this file.

Here are a few things you can check:

Build Process: Ensure that the build process (npm run build) in your Dockerfile completes successfully without any errors. This process is responsible for generating the dist folder and the main file within it.

File Structure: Verify that the dist/main file is present in your project directory before building the Docker image. You can do this by navigating to the directory where your Dockerfile is located and checking if the dist/main file exists.

File Copying: Double-check the COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist line in your Dockerfile. This line is responsible for copying the built files from the development stage to the production stage. Ensure that it's correctly copying the dist directory containing the main file.

Volume Mounting: If you're using volume mounting during development or deployment, ensure that it's not interfering with the file structure within the container. Volume mounting can override the files within the container, so make sure it's not causing the main file to be inaccessible.

By verifying these points, you should be able to identify the issue causing the main file to be missing within the Docker container. Once you've resolved the issue, rebuild your Docker image and try running it again.